# Почему не обновляется база данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу сайт на phр (в данный момент админ-блок). Имеется файл edit_text.php, который выводит список страниц для редактирования без индентификатора id, а если он есть, то форму с содержанием соответствующей страницы:

```
if (isset($id)) 
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id='$id'", $db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    print <<<HERE

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="update_text.php">
        <p>
            <label>Введите название страницы (тэг title)<br>
                <input value="$myrow[title]" type="text" name="title" id="title">
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Введите краткое описание страницы<br>
                <input value="$myrow[meta_d]" type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d">
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Введите ключевые слова для страницы<br>
                <input value="$myrow[meta_k]" type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k">
            </label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>
                <p>Введите полный текст страницы с тэгами</p>
            <p>
                <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="20">$myrow[text]</textarea>
            </label>
            </p>
        </p>

        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="$myrow[id]">

        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Сохранить изменения">
            </label>
        </p>
    </form>

HERE;

}
else
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM settings", $db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
        printf("<p><a href='edit_text.php?id=%s'>%s</a></p>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['title']);
    } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
```

потом данные отправляются в файл update_text.php.

```
if (isset($id) && isset($title) && isset($meta_d) && isset($meta_k) && isset($text))            
{
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='$title', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', text='$text' WHERE id='$id')", $db);
    if ($result == true) 
    {
        echo"<p>Текст страницы успешно отредактирован.</p>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo"<p>Текст страницы не отредактирован.</p>";
    }

}
else
{
    echo"<p>Вы ввели не все данные, поэтому страница не была отредактирована. Вернитесь назад и заполните все поля.</p>";
}

?>
```

Какие данные ни введи, выполняется строка:

```
echo"<p>Текст страницы успешно отредактирован.</p>".
```

Что делать? Почему не обновляется база данных?

Comment: Ох, слишком много букв. У меня нет сил столько читать и вникать… может быть, найдутся желающие. Вообще Вам правильнее было бы свести этот пример к минимальному, точно демонстрирующему именно саму проблему. Тогда всем было бы легче.

Comment: @MultiTeemer Для правильного форматирования кода нужно выделить код и кликнуть по кнопке 101010 (или добавить четыре пробела перед каждой строчкой). Текст заголовка должен отражать суть вопроса.

Comment: Поддерживаю предложение kirelagin'а. Лишний код ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

@Асисяськин, я не сомневаюсь, что Вы видели статью в инете про ООП, но судя по тому, что написали, Вы не имеете понятия что это такое.
Начнем с того, что если Вы хотите ООП, то сделайте так:

```
class Params { }

class BaseUpdate {
final static function update($plink) {
if ($plink->id && $plink->title && $plink->meta1 && $plink->meta2 && $plink->text) {
mysql_query("update `table` set `title`='".$plink->title."' where `id`='".$plink->id."';"); // Лень все писать
}
}
}
```

И сам вызов:

```
$p = new Params;
$p->id = 1;
$p->title = 'some title';
$p->meta1 = 'm1';
$p->meta2 = 'm2';
$p->text = 'text';

BaseUpdate::update($p);
```

Это как пример. Думаю, что применение ООП Вы можете найти там же, где Вы нашли тот бред, что написали :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это потому, что $id равно неизвестно чему. Добавьте дебажный аутпут, чтобы понять, что в переменной $id. Наверняка мусор какой-нибудь. Если былы бы какая-нибудь синтаксическая ошибка в запросе, связанная с неудачной склейкой, то вы получили бы ошибку и увидели бы, что "страница не отредактирована"

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='$title', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', text='$text' WHERE id='$id')", $db);
```

попробуйте так:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='".$title."', meta_d='".$meta_d."', meta_k='".$meta_k."', text='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."';");
```

И isset проверяет инициализирована ли у вас переменная, в вашем случае инициализирована.
Используйте trim();

Comment: Поправлю чуть, инициализирована, это когда переменной присвоено значение. isset() проверяет существует ли переменная (может быть просто без значения: $k;), а для проверки значения в переменных замечательно подходит empty();

Answer (score 0):

Нет, просто потому что isset - это функция, которая определяет существование переменной, а она у Вас в лоюбом случае передается.

Т.е. нужно сделать не так:

```
if (isset($param)) {
print "Hello world!";
}
```

А вот так:

```
if (trim($param)) {
print "Hello world!";
}
```

А уже потом выкидываете ваш запрос типа:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='$title', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', text='$text' WHERE id='$id'"), $db);
```

И пишите так:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET `title`='".$title."', `meta_d`='".$meta_d."', `meta_k`='".$meta_k."', `text`='".$text."' WHERE `id`='".$id."';");
```

И все. Работать будет, конечно, если Вы передаете данные :)

P.S:
Самое главное:

```
if ($result == true)
```

НЕЛЬЗЯ ТАК ПИСАТЬ! НИКОГДА ТАК НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ! :)
нужно: 
    if ($result === true)

Answer (score 0):

1) Проверьте существование в таблице записи с id='' или id=0, если тип id - INT; isset возвращает true даже при пустых значениях. Если она есть - сбоит при проверке данных.

2) Для численного id лучше использовать "if (isset($id) && (intval($id) > 0)) {}"

3) Для Update используйте [mysql___affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

```
$q = mysql_query('UPDATE ...etc...');
if (mysql_affected_rows($q)>0) {
  // ok
  }
```

,mysql_query возвращает true для запроса без ошибок, а не для успешно обновленной записи.

4) Я очень надеюсь, что у вас выключен register_globals и вы проверяете входящие данные, иначе все может печально кончиться.

Comment: ЗЫ: по красоте кода, закрывайте одинарные теги (<input /> <br />), даже подсветка ругается)

Comment: Не могу не заметить, что в стандартах HTML ни тег input, ни тег br не требуют закрывающего тега.

Comment: Не требует, но красиво же, когда <input /> вместо <input>. Хотя сам всегда пишу только второй вариант. Если ругается подсветка - она неверная :)

Comment: Не знаю уж как насчёт красиво, но в HTML нет самозакрывающихся тегов. Если кому-то красота важнее, чем синтаксическая корректность — милости прошу.

Comment: Ну это скорее хороший тон + при привычке будет меньше напрягов, когда заказчик захочет сайт на "валидном XHTML". Опять же, работа с XML туда же, там <node1><node2></node1> не прокатит)

Answer (score 0):

Вот это ->
if (isset($id) && isset($title) && isset($meta_d) && isset($meta_k) && isset($text))

Замени на это:
PHP - объектно ориентирован. Почему никто не юзает классы ? Это же гораздо удобнее ? 
 Так вот: 
 1. Создай какой-нибудь common.php, заинклюдь его в конфигу подключения к БД.
 2. В своем файле (где ты пытаешься закинуть ту хрень в БД) сделай инклюд к common.php
 3. после этого:
Содержимое херни, которая в данный момен проверку у тебя рубит:

```
 $base_update = new BaseUpdate();
$result = $base_update->dbupdate($id, $title, $meta_d, $meta_k, $text);
if($result){
   echo"<p>Текст страницы успешно отредактирован.</p>";  
} else {
   echo"<p>Вы ввели не все данные, поэтому страница не была отредактирована.     
   Вернитесь назад и заполните все поля.</p>";
}
```

---

Срдержимое common.php

```
class BaseUpdate { 
       function dbupdate($id, $title, $meta_d, $meta_k, $text) {
       $b = 0;
       $valid = array($id, $title, $meta_d, $meta_k, $text);
       for($i=0; $i<count($valid); $i++){
           if(strlen($valid) > 4){ //Ну-ну... просто я решил так делать с учетом того, что пользователь может ввести, например, пробел, что тоже символ :) Хотя, конструкция несовсем верна, но все же. Это самый простой способ. Я бы еще проверку на наличие необходимых символов в элементе массива ввел. 
               $b++;
           }
           if($b < count($valid)){  
                  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='$title', 
                   meta_d='$meta_d', 
                   meta_k='$meta_k', 
                   text='$text' 
                   WHERE id='$id')", $db);
                   return true;
           } else { return false; }
       }
 }
```

}

---

Собственно.... что я хотел сказать. Проверяйте правильность вводимых значений ДО того, прежде чем из направлять в БД... ибо результат может быть плачевным :))

Answer (score -1):

Ребят а может все таки в его случае все горозда проще =)
Либо товарищь пытается выдернуть глобальные переменные которые отключены.
либо:

данные же вроде POST и принимать их надо соответственно:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET title='".$_POST['title']."', meta_d='".$_POST['meta_d]'."', meta_k='".$_POST['meta_k']."', text='".$_POST['text']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."';", $db);
```

PS: Ну и как сказали выше данные формы проверять надо в любом случае (либо перед событием submit() через яваскрипт, но лучше при получении до записи в базу)
PPS: И еще кое что невкоем случае нельзя отправлять в базу запрос содержащий хтмл теги или хотя бы разрешить только некоторые так как через данный запрос легко запихивается SQL иньекция

Comment: Я думаю, что человек не совсем дурак, чтобы не получать из $_POST. Запрос в базу можно отправлять, который содержит html-теги, иногда даже просто необходимо, но вот отслеживать кавычки нужно. По сути, больше никак инъекцию не сделать, только если не отслеживать кавычки, а в данном случае одинарные.

Comment: Частично согласен с **Alex Silaev**.

Пользуй функцию - mysql_escape_string (если SQL инъекции тебя устрашают) :))
Про нее в инете очень много чего есть :)

Answer (score -1):

> Цитата*текст курсивом*`введите код здесь`<?php

$dar = duenne($kfmze,.e)';

?>